# Which is the best time scheduler in android even my app is not present in Recent?

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am using Alarm manager but the execution depends upon his mood sometime the alarm manager works and some time its not working.
Here the below code of alarm manager with pending intent

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent = new Intent(SetupFakeVideoCall.this, MyBroadcastVideoReceiver.class);
 
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SetupFakeVideoCall.this, 0, intent, 0);
                Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
                time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                time.add(Calendar.SECOND, afterTimeVid);
                assert alarmMgr != null;
                alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

afterTimeVid is the time which i gave it to for execution.

e.g afterTimeVid = 1500  for 15 sec

Answer (score 1):

The call to `AlarmManager.set()` is not precise. It used to be precise (prior to API 19), but this has been changed over time in order to improve battery life.

If you need the alarm to go off at an exact time then you need to use `AlarmManager.setExact()`. If you look at the [documentation for `AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) there are many hints about how to use it. In general, setting exact alarms is discouraged as this prevents Android from using its battery-saving techniques.